# Date - Calendar - Fecha del sistema en JAVA en tiempo real Thread

Tags: java, date, calendar

Intento añadir a un `JLabel` **la fecha y hora del sistema actual** en ejecución la aplicación. Me muestra la fecha y hora del sistema al lanzar/ejecutar el archivo **JAVA** pero no me la actualiza en tiempo de ejecución del programa.

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo?

```
        //Creamos un objeto de la clase Calendar.
        Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
        //Obtenemos el valor del año, mes, día, hora, minuto y segundo del sistema.
        //Usando el método get y el parámetro correspondiente.
        int ano = fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int mes = fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int dia = fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hora = fecha.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minuto = fecha.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int segundo = fecha.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        //System.out.println("Fecha Actual: "+dia+ "/" +(mes+1)+ "/" +ano);
        //System.out.printf("Hora Actual: %02d:%02d:%02d %n", hora, minuto, segundo);
        label_fechasistema.setText(""+dia+"/"+mes+1+"/"+ano+"    "+hora+":"+minuto+":"+segundo);
```

Imagen: https://s23.postimg.org/uossimngb/fecha_sistema.png

Comment: Cuando compones un String el programa no tiene ni idea de lo que significa. Si quieres actualizar la fecha que aparece en el label, tendrás que actualizar tú el valor que se muestra (probablemente mediante un *Thread*). De todas formas ¿cuál sería la utilidad? El usuario puede ver la fecha y la hora en el reloj del sistema...

Comment: No es tanto como utilidad sino es para añadir la clase Calendar a mi proyecto (requisito) y he decidido hacerlo de esta manera.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;
/**
 *
 * @author aandres
 */
public class RelojModeloUtil extends Observable
 {
     /**
      * Lanza un timer cada segundo.
      */
     public RelojModeloUtil()
     {
         Timer timer = new Timer();
         timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 1000);
     }

     /**
      * main de prueba de esta clase.
      * No necesita una ventana para funcionar.
      */
     public static void main (String [] args)
     {
         RelojModeloUtil modelo = new RelojModeloUtil();
         modelo.addObserver (new Observer()
         {
             public void update (Observable unObservable, Object dato)
             {
                 System.out.println (dato);
             }
         });
     }

     /**
      * Clase que se mete en Timer, para que se le avise cada segundo.
      */
     TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask()
     {
         /**
          * Método al que Timer llamará cada segundo. Se encarga de avisar
          * a los observadores de este modelo.
          */
         public void run() 
         {
             setChanged();
             notifyObservers(new Date());
         }
     };
}
```

La clase Reloj visual

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Observable;
import java.util.Observer;

import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

/**
 * Visual para mostrar el reloj.
 * Es un JLabel que recibe un Observable de cambio de fecha.
 */
public class RelojVisual extends JLabel
 {
     /**
      * Se pasa un observable de fecha/hora. El Observable debe pasar un
      * Date a esta visual para que la presente.
      */
     public RelojVisual(Observable modelo)
     {
         // La fecha/hora se pinta en el centro de este JLabel
         this.setHorizontalAlignment((SwingConstants.CENTER));

         // Suscripción al cambio de fecha/hora en el modelo recibido.
         modelo.addObserver (new Observer ()
         {
             // Método al que el Observable llamará cuando se cambie
             // la fecha/hora. El arg se espera que sea un Date.
             public void update(java.util.Observable o, Object arg) 
             {
                 final Object fecha = arg;

                 // Se actualiza en pantalla la fecha/hora.
                 SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable()
                 {
                     public void run()
                     {
                         setText (format.format(fecha));
                     }
                 });
             }
         });

         // Se da una dimension al JLabel.
         this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (200, 50));
     }

     /**
      * Cambia el formato de presentacion de la fecha/hora en pantalla.
      */
     public void setFormat (SimpleDateFormat unFormato)
     {
         format = unFormato;
     }

     /**
      * Clase para mostrar una fecha/hora en formato texto.
      */
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
}
```

Finalmente tienes un componente de reloj que puedes agregar en cualquier parte de tu sistema de la siguiente manera :

```
RelojVisual r = new RelojVisual(new RelojModeloUtil());
frame.add(r);
```

Answer (score -1):

La opción de Angeldev es válida. Como bien dijo SJuan76, debo utilizar `Thread`. Lanzamos un hilo el cual integre en una etiqueta `JLabel` dentro de un `JFrame` la hora del sistema actual, la puedo obtener tanto con la clase `Date` como con la clase `Calendar`.

**Hora.java**

```
public class Hora extends Thread{
    private JLabel etiqueta;
    public Hora(JLabel etiqueta){
       this.etiqueta = etiqueta;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(true){
           Date hoy = new Date();
           SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
           etiqueta.setText(sdf.format(hoy));
           try{
              sleep(1000); //Segundo a segundo... 
           }catch(Exception e){
              e.getMessage();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

**Index.java**

```
public class Index extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public Index() {
        initComponents();
        Hora hilo = new Hora(etiqueta);
        hilo.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo extraño es que si la hora supera las 12 del mediodía luego si quiere mostrar las 3 de la tarde, pone 3:12:56 en lugar de 15:12:56

Comment: Si en eso está el problema debes cambiar en la clase Hora.java esto: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
           etiqueta.setText(sdf.format(hoy)); por ésto: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
           etiqueta.setText(sdf.format(hoy));

Comment: Gracias por el apunte.

Comment: Si te sirvio indica que mi comentario te ayudó a resolver el problema, pulsando sobre la flechita up junto al comentario..